# How to create a cached context in Spark using Apache Livy?

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-emr, livy

I would like to create a cached context using Apache Livy, such that while submitting spark jobs, it does not require creating a new context every time.

Comment: Have you seen https://gethue.com/how-to-use-the-livy-spark-rest-job-server-api-for-sharing-spark-rdds-and-contexts/?

Comment: Yes. But there, they mentioned about shared contexts while using interactive sessions, not for submitting jars